# Swap text position between the parent text and children text content

Tags: html, css

Can someone please share the magic trick how to work around this things preferably with CSS only. Considering the content width can change overtime, so absolute positioning isn't a thing.

```html
<span class='parent'>
  <span class='first'>First</span>
  Third
  <span class='second'>Second</span>
</span>
```

P.S: Moving `child span` higher in the DOM tree isn't an acceptable solution, since the structure is generated by the JS library :)

Comment: `.first` doesn't have a closing tag, could you update your HTML? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) of flexbox:

```css
.parent {
  display:inline-flex;
}
.parent > * {
  margin:0 2px; /*put back the whitespace removed by flex*/
}
.first {
  order:-2;
}
.second {
  order:-1;
}
```

```html
<span class='parent'>
  <span class='first'>First</span>
  Third
  <span class='second'>Second</span>
</span>
```